# STR_TO_DATE() function of MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, string-to-datetime

I have date in this format `5 Mar 1985  0:00` stored in table as `VARCHAR`.
I want to convert it into `Datetime`, I am using the `STR_TO_DATE()` as follows:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(birth_date, '%d %m %Y %h:%i') FROM student WHERE pk = 29
```

But it returns `NULL`.

Comment: You should be using MySQL's standard date format instead of your own custom one. If you did you wouldn't have to worry about this.

Comment: I actually have the values already stored in the table (birth_date varchar 100) I need to convert it into datetime.

Comment: See: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Answer (score 5):

Try this format - `'%e %b %Y %k:%i'`, for example -

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('5 Mar 1985 2:33', '%e %b %Y %k:%i') dt;
+---------------------+
| dt                  |
+---------------------+
| 1985-03-05 02:33:00 |
+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `STR_TO_DATE(birth_date, '%d %M %Y %h:%i')` instead

`%m` = month in integer
`%M` = month in string(ex: Mar)

Comment: Maybe because the date is in an invalid format? It should have been '5 Mar 1985 00:00'. Try : `STR_TO_DATE(birth_date, '%d %M %Y 0%h:%i')`

Comment: Found this one working
STR_TO_DATE(birth_date, '%d %b %Y  %i:%s')